# React Material UI tabs not highlighting active tab in combination with React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs

Why is my **active tab** highlighting with [Material UI tabs](https://v4.mui.com/components/tabs/#tabs) not working?

I have a Menu component:

```
/** @jsx jsx */

import { jsx } from '@emotion/react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import MyTabs from 'app/components/MyTabs';

const Menu = ({ data }: Props) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return data.menu.items?.length ? (
    <MyTabs menuItems={data.menu.items} value={location.pathname} />
  ) : null;
};

export default Menu;
```

Then I have MyTabs component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { jsx} from '@emotion/react';
import { Tabs, Tab } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyTabs = ({ items, value }: Props) => {

  return items.length ? (
    <Tabs
      value={value}
      orientation="horizontal"
      variant="scrollable"
      scrollButtons="off"
    >
      {items.map((item) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          {console.log(value)}
          <Tab
            key={item.title}
            // tabIndex={index + 1}
            label={item.title}
            value={item.url}
            to={item.url}
            component={Link}
            disableRipple
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </Tabs>
  ) : null;
};

export default MyTabs;
```

I can't figure out why the active tab isn't working? The `to` and `value` properties have the same values.

Another thing. I get this error message in the console:

> Material-UI: The value provided to the Tabs component is invalid. None
> of the Tabs' children match with `/topics`. You can provide one of
> the following values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, when running this code I received the error `"Material-UI: The Tabs component doesn't accept a Fragment as a child. Consider providing an array instead."`

So I removed the `React.Fragment` JSX tag. This solved a lot of errors that were occurring, except when you click on a tag, it will go to the URL, but it won't highlight.

I believe you need to use the `onChange` prop with Tabs to specify the `value` change when you're clicking on a `Tab`.

So I created an `onChange` handler and a React Hook to track the value, based on the input URL.

```
import React from "react";

import { jsx } from "@emotion/react";
import { Tabs, Tab } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const MyTabs = ({ items, value }: Props) => {
  const [tabValue, setTabValue] = React.useState(value);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setTabValue(newValue);
  };

  return items.length ? (
    <Tabs
      value={tabValue}
      orientation="horizontal"
      variant="scrollable"
      scrollButtons="off"
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Tab
          key={item.title}
          label={item.title}
          value={item.url}
          to={item.url}
          component={Link}
          disableRipple
        />
      ))}
    </Tabs>
  ) : null;
};

export default MyTabs;
```

This solves the issue of being able to highlight the active Tab. As for displaying what is within each Tab, that will be a different story, but for now, the above should work to highlight individual tabs. I would need to see further code if you have trouble displaying data within each tab.